# Cygwin installation for a novice

Tags: cygwin

How do I install Cygwin and Postgresql? I need a cygwin installation that comes with postgresql database engine as well as with perl.

Comment: http://cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 2):

Just execute your cygwin installer once more, and have a good look in the Select Packages view.

Postgresql 9.2 should be there under the "Database" node; click to expand.

Likewise, Perl is there under the "Perl" tree node.